# how to generate code coverage (php unit test ) only future code in symfony frameworks?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, code-coverage

I need to generate php-unit code coverage only for new methods, should not consider old codes.

Is there any way to generate for new methods?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible as PHPUnit doesn't know which methods are new.

One way of making sure that your new methods are covered by tests is making sure that coverage never goes down. After making the change, coverage should be the same or higher as it was before the change. You can make it a pass condition on your CI server so that no pull request degrading coverage is merged.